# Shorten for loop for getting paths

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently trying to get the whole pathname of txt files in multiple directories.
The directory structure looks something like this containing a couple thousand image-folder:

- root_dir

  - image1

    - image1.gt.txt
    - image1.stuff.png
    - image1.stuff2.png
  - image2

    - image2.gt.txt
    - etc

The current code is:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathname, topdown=False):
    for file in files:
        if file.split('.')[-1] == 'txt':
            gt_txt = file
            full_path = os.path.join(root, gt_txt)
```

Is there a way to shorten this loop in terms of code and/or runtime or is it even reasonable to shorten it?

Comment: You can use `str.endswith` method instead of splitting the string and comparing it.

Comment: Yeah, that would shorten it a bit, thanks.